# How to form a matrix of distances between sites in T-SQL?

Tags: sql, t-sql

I have all the data (sites and distances already).

Now I have to form a string matrix to use as an input for a python script.

I have sites and distances as (returned from a query):

```
A|B|5
A|C|3
A|D|9
B|C|7
B|D|2
C|D|6
```

What is the most effective way (fastest) to create likewise matrix:

```
  A|B|C|D
A|0|5|3|9
B|5|0|7|2
C|3|7|0|6
D|9|2|6|0
```

I clearly ask for the most effective way, because currently, we are using cursor (fast_forward) and can't get a result for more than 600 sites.

Thanks

Comment: Any reason for not doing it with Python?

Comment: Well, there is a web page that is showing results given from the python script, and the input for that script is output of that matrix, are you saying I should return 600 rows to the py script and let the python create the matrix?

Answer (score 0):

You can use conditional aggregation:

```
select x,
       max(case when y = 'A' then distance else 0 end) as A,
       max(case when y = 'B' then distance else 0 end) as B,
       max(case when y = 'C' then distance else 0 end) as C,
       max(case when y = 'D' then distance else 0 end) as D
from t cross apply
     (values (col1, col2), (col2, col1)) v(x, y)
group by x;
```

I will caution you about attempting to scale this.  SQL Server has a limit on the number of columns that a query can returned.  It won't be able to scale much beyond 600 sites.

Comment: thanks, and yes, that is why I've posted this question here, it is beyond my skills to solve, the number of sites can be even bigger